# iOS camera's image rotation got in AS3

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, camera, rotation

I'm developing a non-native iOS App using AS3 over Flash CS5.5. The app has the feature of taking photos with both cameras (obviously one at any time, not at the same time), and my problem consists in I don't know how to deal with the rotation of the image i'm seeing on my device.

I'm looking for a solution but don't have any which solves my problem.

Here is my code:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.DisplayObject;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.StageAlign;
    import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
    import flash.events.ActivityEvent;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.media.Camera;
    import flash.media.Video;

    public class Main extends Sprite
    {

        private var cam:Camera;
        private var vid:Video;


        public function Main()
        {
            super();

            // support autoOrients
            stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
            stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
            cam = Camera.getCamera();

            if (!cam) 
            {
                trace("No camera is installed.");
            }
            else 
            {
               connectCamera();
            }
        }

        private function connectCamera():void 
        {
            cam.setMode(320, 480, 25); 
            cam.setQuality(0,100);
            vid             = new Video();
            vid.width       = cam.width;
            vid.height      = cam.height; 
            vid.attachCamera(cam);
            addChild(vid);    
        }
    }
}
```

---

First of all thanks for your time. I've already updated the autoOrientation settings, and this is the code I'm managing:

```
    package 
        {
            import flash.display.DisplayObject;
            import flash.display.Sprite;
            import flash.display.StageAlign;
            import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
            import flash.events.ActivityEvent;
            import flash.events.MouseEvent;
            import flash.media.Camera;
            import flash.media.Video;
            import flash.events.StageOrientationEvent;
            import flash.display.StageOrientation;


            public class Main2 extends Sprite
            {

                private var cam:Camera;
                private var vid:Video;
                public var _currentOrientation:String;




                public function Main2()
                {
                    cam = Camera.getCamera();

                    if (! cam)
                    {
                        trace("No camera is installed.");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        connectCamera();
                    }
                    stage.addEventListener(StageOrientationEvent.ORIENTATION_CHANGING, orientationChangeListener);
                }

                private function connectCamera():void
                {
                    cam.setMode(480, 320, 25);
                    cam.setQuality(0,100);
                    vid= new Video();
                    vid.width = cam.width;
                    vid.height = cam.height;
                    vid.attachCamera(cam);
                    addChild(vid);

                }

                private function orientationChangeListener(e:StageOrientationEvent):void
                {
                    switch (e.afterOrientation)
                    {
                        case StageOrientation.DEFAULT :
                            _currentOrientation = "DEFAULT";
                            //set rotation value here
                            stage.rotation = 0;
                            break;

                        case StageOrientation.ROTATED_RIGHT :
                            _currentOrientation = "ROTATED_RIGHT";
                            //set rotation value here
                            stage.rotation = -90;
                            break;

                        case StageOrientation.ROTATED_LEFT :
                            _currentOrientation = "ROTATED_LEFT";
                            //set rotation value here
                            stage.rotation = 90;
                            break;

                        case StageOrientation.UPSIDE_DOWN :
                            _currentOrientation = "UPSIDE_DOWN";
                            //set rotation value here
                            stage.rotation = 180;
                            break;
                    }
                }


            }
}
```

Despite of the switch-case sentences, when you launch the "app" you see the image of the camera 90degrees rotated, and when you put the device (iPhone 4) to landscape (right or left) the image puts well. And when you rotate back, the image gets bad as the launching one.

Thank you in advance.

PS: Sorry for my English.
PS2: Edited.

Answer (score 0):

You need to listen for orientation changes from the device and rotate the captured image accordingly.

```
import flash.events.StageOrientationEvent;
import flash.display.StageOrientation;

public var _currentOrientation:String;

stage.addEventListener(StageOrientationEvent.ORIENTATION_CHANGING, orientationChangeListener);

private function orientationChangeListener (e:StageOrientationEvent):void {

switch (e.afterOrientation) {
case StageOrientation.DEFAULT :
_currentOrientation = "DEFAULT";
//set rotation value here
break;

case StageOrientation.ROTATED_RIGHT :
_currentOrientation = "ROTATED_RIGHT";
//set rotation value here
break;

case StageOrientation.ROTATED_LEFT :
_currentOrientation = "ROTATED_LEFT";
//set rotation value here
break;

case StageOrientation.UPSIDE_DOWN :
_currentOrientation = "UPSIDE_DOWN";
//set rotation value here
break;
}
}
```

Note that this listener is fired only after an orientation change has occurred, so I set a global variable, _currentOrientation, and then test the value of it whenever I capture an image.

One other thing to bare in mind is that there is also an UNKNOWN orientation state.

Comment: Hi, thanks for you quick response, but there is something I missed: your code response to an stage's orientation change, isn't it? 

Maybe I did not explain myself well (sorry!): when i access to one of both iPhone's camera, I see the image (camera image, not captured image) rotate 90 degrees. My problem is I can't rotate the stage (don't know why) and can't rotate the camera.

Thanks again,
DGM.-

Comment: Not sure why that's happening. When you access the camera it should auto orientate with no Actionscript interaction. Have you enabled autoOrientation in your publish settings?

Comment: Thanks Croosky, I've edited my previous question cos I'm a newie poster ^^.